# В каком файле в woocommerce формируется заказ?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, woocommerce

Стоит задача реализовать оптовые цены, без использования плагина. Цены не подходят под формулу, формируются произвольно.

Необходима возможность задать оптовую цену в вариативном товаре к каждой вариации, оптовая цена зависит от кол-ва приобретаемой продукции.

План таков: добавить поля для ввода кол-ва и ввода оптовой цены для каждой вариации, далее в файлах корзины и оформления менять через условие цену. Но не знаю, как подставлять свои значения в момент формирования заказа (В админке и на почте нужны данные с учётом опта).

Как это можно сделать грамотно и безопасно и в каком файле происходит формирование заказа?

P.S. Если решение потенциально кривое - подскажите, в каком двигаться направлении.

Comment: Решение кривое, путь поиска решения ещё более кривой. Заказы формируются не "в файле", а базе. Без плагиов такие вещи не делаются в принципе. Можно конечно писать свой, если нет подходящих. А плагинофобия лечится изучением матчасти.

Comment: Свои поля задать через метабоксы, цену формировать через хуки цены вариативного товара. Обо всем этом отвечал уже тут на SO, поищите в моих ответах. Сегодня нет времени, к сожалению, дать полноценный ответ.

Comment: @KAGGDesign: Я поищу, большое спасибо)

Comment: @SeVlad: Спасибо за совет) У меня нет плагинофобии, не удалось найти подходящий плагин.

Comment: @KAGGDesign: Я в итоге нашёл плагин, называется он bulk discount. Может я не совсем верно передал свою идею для решения задачи, но разобрав код плагина пришёл к тому, что он работает как раз по принципу, который я изложил (может не совсем понятно). Там нет параметров настройки для каждой конкретной вариации, но дописав можно получить то, что я и хотел.